# How do you set a property value in C++ WinRT?

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-runtime

Using VS2019, Win10, SDK 10.0..18363.0, Platform Toolset v142.

I know nothing of C# and I didn't even know that WinRT existed until recently.  I'm having to deal with WinRT only because it appears that I have to in order to deal with BluetoothLE and the Win10 APIs.

That being said, I have code from https://github.com/DerekGn/WinBle that works but it is only a POC and not a complete solution.

In the code I am trying to modify I first locate the device that I want with

```
// Create watcher
BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher;        
// fill in watcher filter
 watcher.AdvertisementFilter().Advertisement().LocalName().c_str() == L"DomasG9630";
```

Once it is located I then get the device object with

```
auto device = co_await BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(deviceAddress);
```

Now, according to the MS docs for the BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync Method they say in the Remarks.

> Creating a BluetoothLEDevice object by calling this method alone
> doesn't (**necessarily**) initiate a connection.  To initiate a
> connection, set GattSession.MaintainConnection to true...

Well, after getting the device object, the device.ConnectionStatus() returns Disconnected so, apparently, the "necessarily" in the remarks refers to me.

So I need to set the GattSession.MaintainConnection property to true.  Sounds easy enough but no matter now I construct it I get compile errors.

Docs say GattSession is a class under GenericAttributeProfile.  If I let the Intellisense take me down the yellow brick road I get

```
GenericAttributeProfile::GattSession::MaintainConnection(true);
```

But with that I get the error "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object".

But what object?  I tried to make it part of the device object but that failed.
My next line of code was to set a GUID in order to filter the GetGATTServices

```
GUID DomasMainServiceGuid = { 0x0000fff0, 0x0000, 0x1000, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x5f, 0x9b, 0x34, 0xfb };
```

and then call the GetGATTServices with

```
auto services = co_await device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(DomasMainServiceGuid);
```

I then tried to call GenericAttributeProfile after that.  Still errors.

I now see that I apparently need to create a GATTSession object. So, using the device object that I already have, I put the line

```
auto connect = co_await GenericAttributeProfile::GattSession::FromDeviceIdAsync(device.DeviceId())
```

But then I get the error

> no suitable conversion from winrt::hstring to  const
> winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothDeviceId exists

So my first question is; how do I get a const winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothDeviceId to use as a parameter?

And then, once I get that object, how do I set the MaintainConnection property to true?

Any help with this frustrating WinRT would be appreciated.

Ed

Comment: "*I know nothing of C#*" - good, because nothing in this question refers to C# :-) "*I'm having to deal with WinRT only because it appears that I have to in order to deal with BluetoothLE and the Win10 APIs*" - no, you don't *have* to use WinRT at all.  It is just a wrapper library written in pure C++ code. You *can* access the underlying APIs (which are exposed as COM objects) without using WinRT, but doing so would be more work since you would be takng on more responsibility over memory/resource management, etc.

Comment: Do not worry about the connection. Simple read services from your device and the connection will be established. Use Read From Device flag to be sure,

Comment: `BluetoothDeviceId::FromId(string)` lets you create a `BluetoothDeviceId` from a device ID string. From that you can get a GattSession. And then you can do `gattSession.MaintainConnection(true)`. The problem isn't C++/WinRT. It's the design of the Windows Runtime classes you are using. (You'd have the same problems in C# or Rust.)

Comment: From what I gather it seems that WinRT is a wrapper around Windows Runtime which was what C# uses from what I understand.  So I would think that WinRT is just a pseudo C# but that is another discussion since I know neither.

Comment: I was trying to use WinRT because, again from what I understand, I can connect with a Bluetooth Low Energy device (if the device is already paired)  with C++ with BleDevice.h, BleGattServices.h, etc but you cannot pair a device without WinRT.  At least, again, as far as I understood.

Comment: I'm mostly trying to write to the device.  I'm wondering if writing will establish a connection the way reading will.  And again...will it do this if the device is not yet paired.  That, actually, is my first concern.  I just got stopped in my tracks when I tried to set a simple property.

I finally saw where I needed a GattSession object but then got stopped with the parameter.  No matter what format I tried I would get the error that there was no conversion from the format that I used to winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothDeviceId

Comment: Actually I had tried char and const char and maybe some other but I had not tried string.  I will give that a try.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the comment very well.  I see now you are mentioning 
BluetoothDeviceId::FromId(string)
Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: Trying to use the solution posited by Raymond Chen above, it is still a No Go...
I tried BluetoothDeviceId::FromId(device.DeviceId() but the error was that
BluetoothDeviceId had no member FromID.  I tried to follow the Intellisense 
with both Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothDeviceId and
winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothDeviceId but there was no FromID.
I finally did a 

auto deviceID = BluetoothLEDevice::FromIdAsync(device.DeviceId());

Notice the LEDevice here.  I then tried to get the GattSession with

Comment: auto oGattSession = co_await GattSession::FromDeviceIdAsync(deviceID);

but I get the compile error

E0312 no suitable user-defined conversion from "winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothLEDevice>" to 
"const winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothDeviceId" exists

So I guess that I need a BluetoothID and not a BluethoothLEId.  I'll keep plugging away at it.